# How to save picturebox's paint function drawings only on bitmap in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

1. I'm drawing shapes on the PictureBox control using Paint event of it.
2. May I know how to save drawn shapes only on a bitmap without the picture box image(current).
3. I don't want to save the PictureBox image.
4. I have created the bitmap from the image(White background image) for saving a drawing on it.
5. I want to save it on created bitmap image(4).

```
Image WhiteBackGroundImage=Image.FromFile("path");//fetching white back ground image.
Bitmap pic=new Bitmap(WhiteBackGroundImage);//creating bitmap
pictureBoxImage.DrawToBitmap(pic,pictureBoxImage.ClientRectangle);
pic.Save("path", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: If you are drawing by GDI+, why do you use `PictureBox` at all? It could be even a simple `Panel`.

Comment: And in the course of all that you have created a bunch of memory leaks

Comment: @taffer sorry, it was started with PictureBox initially, It is difficult for me to change everywhere now.

Comment: Do you mean you have an Image which you do not want to save? In that case move all Paint calls to a function void pintMyStuff(Graphics g..) which you can call to either draw on the control or the bitmap. For the former pass out the e.Graphics from the Paint event for the latter a Graphics object Created from the bitmap. - Btw: Drawing onto a PBox is better than onto a Panel as PBox was made for this. Panel was not.

Comment: @Taw, Thank you, I applied it, working.